# Firefox rendering a mysterious character in HTML generated from Markdown with the text OBJ written on it

Tags: html, markdown

I am generating HTML from Markdown (using showdown.js), and am encountering a very mysterious issue that I am unable to understand. Given the following text:

```
<h2>Foobar</h2>

￼￼￼￼￼<figure>
    <img src="foo.gif">
    <figcaption>foo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Firefox, and *only Firefox*, is rendering the generated HTML as follows (I am showing an image below because the mysterious characters are un-selectable):

[image: mysterious character in the render]

[image: the character is also visible in the code]

This does not happen in either Safari or in Chrome. Any explanation?

Comment: You need to supply the markup and code that reproduces the problem for us. As it stands, what you have given does not do that.

Comment: check that the js you are trying is compatible with your Firefox or not.

Comment: @Rob, I am not sure what you mean by "the markup" that reproduces the problem. Literally, the text I've provided above is what I have. It is mixed Markdown and HTML, and I am putting it through `showdown.js` and Firefox is doing what I am describing. Since I am unable to select that funky [OBJ] character using a text editor, I've provided a screenshot of it. @Gahan, the same `showdown.js` does not create this problem with any other page of text in Firefox, so yes, it is compatible with FF. And, this problem does not occur with any other browser.

Comment: HTML is a "markup language" because it is used to "mark up" text for structure or presentation. What you show is HTML. Markdown cannot be presented in a web browser directly. Perhaps this is the cause of your issue but, from what you show, we are unable to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are **[object replacement characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm)** with the Unicode codepoint of U+FFFC.

To get rid of them, do a find and replace for it with an empty string as a replacement using an editor of your choice.

Here is the character itself for easier copying. Between the two "a" letters, there is one object replacement character. Delete the second "a", then press the left arrow key once and delete the first "a" to only keep the replacement character in the field.

```
a￼a
```

Comment: thanks for the lead. I was unable to get Visual Studio Code (my editor of choice) to find anything, but in BBEdit I saw "empty spaces" where that character was appearing. Again, I was not able to do a "find and replace" but simply deleting that "empty space" got rid of that character. I am curious as to where it came from in the first place given I typed the text by hand. And, why wasn't it showing up in either Safari or Chrome?

Comment: @punkish Safari and Chrome renders those characters as whitespace (they only modify the cursor behavior a bit). Firefox chose a different approach for this, possibly because of issues like this.